# PDO INSERT not working but no errors

Tags: php, pdo

I made this script to generate a string and insert it into a database,
but it doesn't insert into the database even though i get no errors what so ever.

```
$pare = $id;
$time_stamp = date('H:m');
$token = 'token'. md5($pare . $time_stamp);

echo " Token: -" . $token;
try {
  $database = $this->server->connect_to_database('3250900');
  $sql_query_string = "INSERT INTO `authentication_tokens` (`id`, `user_id`, `token`, `timestamp`) VALUES (:n, :user_id, :token, :time_stamp)";
  $statement = $database->prepare($sql_query_string); //Prepare the sql statement
  $statement->execute([ ':n'          => NULL,
                        ':user_id'    => $pare,
                        ':token'      => $token,
                        ':time_stamp' => $time_stamp]); //execute query
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e;
}


print_r($statement);
```

Comment: Have you configured PHP to show errors? See it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Also, how do you initiate PDO? Try to add this `PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` so it actually breaks when there is an error

Comment: Yes i do, thats the thing. It makes it look like i have no errors and everything works great, but it doesnt do anything...

Comment: You have no errors because you don't check them.

Comment: i check with ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: These are not php errors, php works fine. These are mysql errors and you don't process them.

Comment: could you maybe elaborate? i though (Exception $e) in the try catch gave me the mysql errors

Comment: You can use `PDOException $e` to display exact error that MySQL throwing, and display error by `$e-getMessage()`.

Comment: `PDOStatement::execute` does not throw any error when `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is set, instead, it throws a `PDOException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    $pare = $id;
    $time_stamp = date('H:m');
    $token = 'token'. md5($pare . $time_stamp);


 echo " Token: -" . $token;
 try {
    $database = $this->server->connect_to_database('3250900');

    $stmt = $database ->prepare ("INSERT INTO `authentication_tokens` (`id`, `user_id`, `token`, `timestamp`) VALUES (:n, :user_id, :token, :time_stamp)");
    $stmt -> bindParam(':n', NULL);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':user_id', $pare);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':token', $token);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':timestamp', $time_stamp);
    $result = $stmt -> execute();

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
           trigger_error('Error occured while trying to insert into the DB:' . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }

    if ($result) {
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }
```